# How do I change AppBarLayout while changing the fragment while retaining NavigationDrawer?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have the following situation:

I have activity with NavigationDrawer and several fragments between which I can navigate. The activity includes AppBarLayout with a drop down calendar.

[image]

Content Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content_main_screen"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main_screen">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/backgroundScreens"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation">
    </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

App Bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:expanded="false">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1.0">

                <com.github.sundeepk.compactcalendarview.CompactCalendarView
                    android:id="@+id/compactCalendarView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:compactCalendarBackgroundColor="@color/backgroundScreens"
                    app:compactCalendarTextSize="14sp"
                    app:compactCalendarTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:compactCalendarCurrentDayBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                    app:compactCalendarCurrentDayTextColor="@color/black"
                    app:compactCalendarCurrentSelectedDayBackgroundColor="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:background="@color/backgroundScreens">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewToolbarTittle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutDatePickerButton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewDatePickerAppBarMainScreen"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageViewArrowAppBarMainScreen"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewDatePickerAppBarMainScreen"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_calendar" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main_screen" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.diary.MainScreen">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main_screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

     <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
         android:id="@+id/navigationView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="start"
         app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
         app:menu="@menu/main_screen_drawer">

     </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The problem is that when I change a fragment to a different one than the one in the picture. I would like to change the toolbar and AppBarLayout. That instead of an extended calendar it would look completely different. But still keep the ability to navigate between fragments, thanks to NavigationDrawer. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can add your `onDestinationChangeListener` in the `Activity` or `Fragment` where the `nav_controller` is set up:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            when (destination.id) {
                R.id.someFragment -> {
                   //change here
                }
                ....
            }
        }
```